# What is the cardinality of $A$ if $A = \{\{A\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of $A$ if $A = \{\{A\}\}$?

I think one is the answer since the outer set has one element, a set. But that seems to simple to be right.

Comment: Do you know any example of a set $A$ satisfying that equation? Can there be one?

Comment: @GerryMyerson In the absence of [the Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) such a thing could be possible. See for example [non-well-founded Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-well-founded_set_theory)

Comment: @Vso, do you think that's what OP has in mind?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm not sure. If the Axiom of Regularity is assumed, then the question has no meaning, since cardinality is only defined for sets (and there wouldn't be a set as described in the question)

Comment: Hey, Nkululeko, care to clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since then the function $f:A\to 1$ with $1=\{\varnothing\}$ that sends $\{A\}\mapsto\varnothing$ is a bijection.

Actually the cardinality of $A=\{A\}$ is $1$ as well.

Of course if $A=\{\{A\}\}$ and $A=\{A\}$ exist and are sets, the [Axiom of Regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) fails. Therefore, this question has no meaning in set theories that contain the Axiom of Regularity (such as the standard ones $\mathsf{ZF}$ and $\mathsf{ZFC}$), since then there exist no sets $A$ with $A=\{\{A\}\}$.

Comment: Your last sentence baffles me. ZF-Reg is also a *set theory*. Certainly this is a finite set, and finite cardinals have meaning *everywhere*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila where do you read me saying that $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ is not a set theory? I'm talking about $\mathsf{ZF}$ (i.e. *plus* regularity)

Comment: *"as cardinality is only defined on sets."*

Comment: @AsafKaragila isn't that the case? If $X$ is not a set, then what does $|X|$ mean?

Comment: My point is that if $A=\{A\}$, then $A$ is not a set when working in a context of regularity, hence the question what $|A|$ is has no meaning.

Comment: Well, if you have choice, then it's an ordinal. If you don't have choice, then it's true that cardinals cannot (necessarily) be globally defined. Nevertheless, well-ordered cardinals are still ordinals. And finite sets are usually always well-ordered.

Comment: @Asaf You've got me baffled as well. If the Axiom of Regularity holds, and $A=\{A\}$, then surely if $\beta$ is an ordinal with $\beta=|A|$ witnessed by a bijective function $f:\beta\to A$, then replacement gives that $A$ is a set, contradicting regularity? Therefore $|A|$ cannot be an ordinal. Are we talking about the same thing here?

Comment: What does Replacement have to do with that? We are talking about ZF-Reg., Surely you can agree that $\{A\}$ is a singleton. I mean, you even proved it yourself, it has a single element. I am saying that without any Regularity or Choice, where you cannot define cardinals globally (i.e. assign to each set a cardinal in a uniform way), you can still do that to well-orderable sets, and finite sets are still well-orderable, so $\{A\}$ still has a cardinality of $1$.

Comment: @Asaf But I'm **not** talking about $\mathsf{ZF}^-$, I'm talking about $\mathsf{ZF}$. I agree that without regularity, $\{A\}$ has a cardinality. *With* regularity it doesn't, though, since $A$ such that $A=\{A\}$ does not even exist.

Comment: Let's start over. $A=\{\{A\}\}$ is provably without a solution assuming ZF. Everyone agree with that. You made a claim that "cardinality" doesn't make sense without Regularity, if such $A$ does exist. And I am pointing out that while it is true that cardinality cannot be defined *uniformly* in ZF-Reg, it *can* be defined for well-orderable sets, which include the finite sets, which include singletons, which include such $A$. Ergo, the cardinality of such set, if it exists, is $1$. End of story.

Comment: @Asaf But I never claimed that cardinality does not make sense without regularity. I claimed that if $A$ is not a set (i.e. does not exist or is a proper class), then it does not make sense to talk about $|A|$, since the cardinality of nonexisting objects or proper classes is not defined. Hence if we assume Regularity, then we can't say anything sensible about $|A|$ for sets $A$ such that $A=\{\{A\}\}$ (as they don't exist). Ergo assuming Regularity, OP's question does not make sense.